# Keyboard Bug or feature on Ubuntu on a MAC?

Tags: keyboard, macbook, mac

I have ubuntu 10.04 on my mac, and i have realized that when i pluged in an USB keyboard (PC) and turn on the numeric keypad if then i removed the keyboard, the keyboard on the mac (this sounds odd, not english spoken person sorry) is completely lost.

Let me try to explain, when removing the USB keyboard with the numeric keypad activated, the built in mac keyboard is mapped like a numeric keyboard ONLY, j=1 k=2 l=3 u=4 ... and so on, and the others keys doesnt work, and the only way to restore normal behaviour is connecting the USB keyboard and turn off from there the numeric keypad, and then removing the usb.

Is this behaviour ok? Is this a feature or a bug?

Macbook 4.1

regards

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a bug to me but one that doesn't have a reasonable fix. I assume you don't have a number-lock key on your Mac keyboard. However you can turn NumLock off with a little application called `numlockx` (`sudo apt-get install numlockx`):

```
numlockx off
```

You can then make a launcher on your desktop (or panel) that calls `bash -c "numlockx off"` so you can quickly turn it off with just a mouse.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i definitely used, but would be great if someone fix this bug.

Comment: and yes you assume correctly, the mac keyboard doesnt have a number-lock key.

Comment: not so much a bug, just a problem with mac's unusual keyboards